# How to set up a git repository in Windows VPS?

Tags: vps, git-remote

I have a VPS - Windows Server 2012 R2 and I already install GIT on the server.

Now I want to set up a repository on it and our team can clone that repository to local computer and work on it.


I try to find the way to set up but I have not found any posts.


How can I set up it? Can I use any tool to set up on vps and commit from local machine?

Answer (score 0):

You need a listener (Apache or ssh) in order for Git on your VPS to listen to Git queries (clone/pull/push)

You can use:

- ssh (with an [ssh server](https://serverfault.com/questions/8411/what-is-a-good-ssh-server-to-use-on-windows))
- IIS (with [Bonobo Git server](https://bonobogitserver.com/))
- https with a Go server (multiplatform) like [Gogs](https://gogs.io/)